# Svn Upgrade 1.9.4 to 1.9.5 (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) leads to svn E200019 Version mismatch error

Tags: ubuntu, svn, ubuntu-14.04, apt, svnserve

After `apt-get update/upgrade` svn server and client were installed,
but any svn operations leads to following error:

```
svn: E200019: Version mismatch in 'svn_subr' (expecting equality): found 1.9.4, expected 1.9.5
svn: E200019: Version mismatch in 'svn_delta' (expecting equality): found 1.9.4, expected 1.9.5
svn: E200019: Version mismatch in 'svn_fs_util' (expecting equality): found 1.9.4, expected 1.9.5
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Just in case if it could help:

```
apt list --installed | awk '{print $1}' | egrep 'svn|subversion' | less

    libsvn1/now
    subversion/now
```

P.S. Originally tried to ask [here](https://www.svnforum.org/forum/opensource-subversion-forums/general-setup-and-troubleshooting/79722-upgrade-1-9-4-to-1-9-5-ubuntu-14-04-lts-leads-to-svn-e200019-version-mismatch-error) - but no luck yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was easy. Have to restart SVN server.